# How to force text recognition running only on the original direction?

Tags: ocr, image-rotation, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, text-recognition

How to force text recognition running only on the original direction?

When i try to recognize "￥6.7"，the result sometimes is right,but sometimes it shows "L'9*",i set direction on

val iiprice = InputImage.fromBitmap(bmprice, 0)

but it dont works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.